# How often can I safely reload nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx

I'd like to run a script that - as frequently as possible - reloads the `nginx` process. I know that usually my system has 33 worker processes, and when I do a reload, I see that all those processes get sent to a "shuttingdown state" and hang around for a few minutes before going away.

I think that if I reload it quicker than the time it takes for all old processes to die, I'll eventually consume resources and make the system unstable?

Is there a way to expedite the killing of the old processes? Or another way to do this?

Comment: The grand question is: Why would you think, you need to do that?

Comment: I want the system to automatically pick up a change in the conf files, and apply it. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Again: Why? If you change your config files faster than nginx can reload, you're doing it wrong, I think... Usually an [`nginx -s reload`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control) is enough.

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is = "you should re-think the design of your system / requirements to not require so many frequent reloads" ?

Comment: That is indeed one underlying aspect, but that's also often easier said than done. So for the moment I'm just curious about your motivation.

Comment: It's still in the design phase, so this feedback is useful. One idea was to go with regular and frequent reloads to pick up any changes. The other idea is to execute a reload with a change, which seems to be the way to go. I certainly prefer this method for all the obvious reasons.